# How to add an item to a custom index in Sitecore programmatically?

Tags: solr, sitecore

I have created my custom Index in Sitecore with `FlatDataCrawler`.
Now I am going to add new item inherited from `AbstractIndexable` to my index.

```
private void Test() {
    var newItem = new ContactIndexable {
        Number = new System.Random().Next(500, 10000),
        MyField = "Item from IMPORTER"
    };
    var index = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("my_index");
    using (var ctx = index.CreateUpdateContext()) {
        //This line doesn't work:
        ctx.Index.Operations.Add(newItem, index.CreateUpdateContext(), index.Configuration);
        index.Refresh(newItem);
    }

}
```

Calling this code causes that only the `GetItemsToIndex` method is called in my custom crawler, but the element is not added to the Index.

So, how can I add a new item to my custom index from code?

This method works correctly and a new element is added to the index:

```
protected override IEnumerable<ContactIndexable> GetItemsToIndex() {
    List<ContactIndexable> items = new List<ContactIndexable>() {
        new ContactIndexable()
        {
             MyField = "Created in crawler"
        }
    };
    return items;
}
```

Comment: Your issue looks similar to [this one](https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/12724/programmatically-adding-items-to-a-custom-solr-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're really close. You have to queue up the context first and then add and commit.

```
using (var solr = ContentSearchManager.GetIndex("my_index'))
{
    var ctx = solr.CreateUpdateContext();
    solr.Operations.Add(newItem, ctx, solr.Configuration);
    ctx.Commit();
}
```

Since this is using SolrNet under the hood, all operations against Solr have to be committed.